# JSF - Marquee shows nothing after reload

Tags: java, html, jsf-2, javabeans, marquee

Somehow the content of the `marquee tag` is empty, after refreshing the page.

```
<f:verbatim><marquee>#{circuitBean.feed}</marquee></f:verbatim>
```

It happened this problem occurred multiple times in my project, as described in my other [**question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21948157/jsf-custom-tags-dynamic-values-disappear-after-refresh).

So I thought this is a general problem, which is not specifically related to my previous question. Does is have to do anything with my `bean-annotations`?

**Backing Bean**

```
@ManagedBean
@ApplicationScoped
public class CircuitBean implements Serializable{

    @EJB
    FeedEJB feedEJB;

    private String feed;

    public String getFeed() {
        feed = feedEJB.getFeedString();
        return feed; 
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Even when setting a variable in JS that holds the feed, it becomes empty after a page refresh!

```
var feed = #{circuitBean.feed};
--> becomes -->
var feed = ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken the marquee tag has been *deprecated* in **HTML 4.0** and higher. It resides in **CSS** these days.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, though the original problem still exists, that the feed becomes empty after a page refresh

Comment: Did the value for feed turn to 'null' during debug on page refresh?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, found my problem and will post it in a sec.

Comment: The `getFeedString()`-method of the `feedEJB` was returning an empty String if the `feed` was not empty before. Though logically the method should return the old feed, if it were already existent.

Comment: Actually I was just thinking it might not be a bad idea to include a check in your getFeed method to make sure the feed isn't empty or null. You can do this by either making an if-condition or perhaps use assertion during build/debug as you probably will assume/know there always should be a feed in production.

Comment: Thanks I came over this solution earlier ago.